# Selected combobox value added twice to an arraylist

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox, itemlistener

I've populated the elements of a combo box using a SQL query and am writing the selected value to an arraylist. When I print out the elements of the arraylist, the value has been added twice. Does anybody know why this is, and how do I stop this from happening?

Extracts from the code:

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM menu WHERE category = 'beverage'");
while (resultSet.next())
{
    beverageJComboBox.addItem(resultSet.getString(1));
    System.out.printf("%s", resultSet.getString(1));
}
```

And for the adding ite to the ArrayList:

```
beverageJComboBox.addItemListener(
     new ItemListener()
     {
          public void itemStateChanged( ItemEvent event )
          {
              billItems.add((String)beverageJComboBox.getSelectedItem());
              System.out.printf("%s", billItems); 
          }
     }// end anonymous inner class
);
```

(Very new to Java!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) instead of `ItemListener`

```
    beverageJComboBox.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

---

Note: use `distinct` keyword in query itself to show the unique record in `JComboBox`.